# Having issue on submitting a run in VSCode using python

Tags: python, azure, visual-studio-code

I am working on building a project with MS Azure, Currently using python in vscode to connect my MS Azure. While running a script run = experiment.run(config) i got an error that ready AttributeError: 'Experiment' object has no attribute 'run'
Any help on why it says this?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2TVs.png)

Comment: Without seeing the code, my guess is that the `Experiment` class does not have an function called `run`.

Comment: Are you using an older version of python perhaps?

Comment: Where and how do you define  or initiate `Experiment`?

Comment: I edited my post and attached a screenshot of what im working with

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a late answer, but I am hoping to help anyone else that might stumble onto this problem in the same course, just like I did. He didn't update the files, so you are correct in assuming it should be `experiment.submit(config)` like in the "after" files, rather than what he writes `experiment.run(config)`.

As Daamian mentions the placement, or in this case rather the naming of the script is the issue. I do not know what magic the instructor works, but when he creates the config variable he declares it as:

```
config = ScriptRunConfig(source_directory='.', script='module3/sdcript.py', compute_target=cpu_cluster_name)
```

But there is no file called 'script.py'. What he expects you to run is the file called 'hello.py' so you need to write your config variable like this instead:

```
config = ScriptRunConfig(source_directory='.', script='module3/hello.py', compute_target=cpu_cluster_name)
```

This is extremely unclear, and has taken me too long to figure out on top of a lot of other issues. But hey, you guys still helped me realize the issue, so thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.core.experiment.experiment?view=azure-ml-py#methods) mentions: the `Experiment` class has no method `run`. Do you mean `get_runs()` or `start_logging()` perhaps?

Comment: Well, I am not completely sure as these are files pre-made by an MS Azure course in. Machine Learning. Trying to access the Experiment class but the instructor of the video used the commant run(config). However when i opened the files the commant submit(config) pre-populated instead of the run command. Running the file using the submit(config) i just ran into another error saying   
    "error": {
        "message": "/Users/michelle/Downloads/building-first-data-science-project-microsoft-azure/module3/script.py script path doesn't exist. The script should be inside the project folder"

Comment: Me running the script should populate a URL that connects my MS Azure account to VSCode

Comment: I am sure that the error you made this post for is due to not having the method `run` in the `Experiment` class. I can see that your teacher used to command somehow, ut I cannot help with that since I do not know the course. That last error suggests that the script you are running (`script.py`) should be in another folder. I think it should be in folder `building-first-data-science-project-microsoft-azure` instead of folder `module3`. See also https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-tools-for-ai/issues/230